# Javascript animation with setInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm creating a simple animation with a comet goes down.

Here is the comet itself:

```
var cometScene = function(){
    var b = document.createElement('div');
    b.id = 'cometio';


    var cometImage = document.createElement('img');

    cometImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/comet1.png');
    b.appendChild(cometImage);

    document.getElementById('wrap').appendChild(b);
}
```

And here is the move:

```
function cometMove(){
    var comet = document.getElementById('cometio');
    var pos = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(scene, 3);

    function scene(){
        if (pos === 1000){
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            pos++;
            comet.style.top = pos + 'px';
            comet.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is it is only happens once and then I have to refresh the page to run an animation again. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use css-animations?. You can easily do it with it. Once you want to stop the animation, change the `class` or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to refresh the page to run an animation again

```
if (pos === 1000){
   clearInterval(interval); /* you have stopped animation here */
}
```

To re-run or keep running, possibly you may just reset the position of comet:

```
if (pos === 1000){
   pos = 0;
}
```